# How do I get the diagonal elements of a matrix/grid from a specific element?

Tags: python, list, matrix, grid, diagonal

I have an 8x8 grid of different numbers, and I want to get the elements of the diagonal that contains a given starting position. Here is an example

```
l = [[str(randint(1,9)) for i in range(8)] for n in range(8)]

>> [
[1 5 2 8 6 9 6 8]
[2 2 2 2 8 2 2 1]
[9 5 9 6 8 2 7 2]
[2 8 8 6 4 1 8 1]
[2 5 5 5 4 4 7 9]
[3 9 8 8 9 4 1 1]
[8 9 2 4 2 8 4 3]
[4 4 7 8 7 5 3 6]
]
```

How would I go about getting the diagonal from the position x=4 and y=3 (so 4th list and 5th element in that list)? So The diagonal I would want would be [5,2,6,4,4,1,3].

Comment: I would suggest looking into the NumPy library: http://www.numpy.org/. In terms if indexing, take a look at their documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html. If you want to stick with lists only, say that in your post.

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? It seems like you want to get a 2-dimensional "diagonal" list given x and y. In your example (x = 4 and y =3), does x refer to rows and y refer to columns? if so, wouldn't the element at (4,3) be 5? Then how do you get [5,2,6,4,4,1,3], which looks like it starts at (0,1) then goes to (1,2), (2,3), and so on?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and explain what the specific problem was.

Comment: @nofinator Yes the x and y represent rows and columns, sorry I was unclear on what they represented. By y=3 I meant the 4th list since the first list is the 0th list, and by x=4 I meant the 5th element in that list. And regarding the last part of your question, I meant the diagonal that includes the given element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the row and column of the top-left item of the diagonal based on the difference of `x` and `y`, and the number of iterations based on the difference between the lower of the two boundaries and the higher of the starting row and column:

```
def diagonal(m, x, y):
    row = max((y - x, 0))
    col = max((x - y, 0))
    for i in range(min((len(m), len(m[0]))) - max((row, col))):
        yield m[row + i][col + i]
```

so that:

```
m = [
    [1, 5, 2, 8, 6, 9, 6, 8],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 1],
    [9, 5, 9, 6, 8, 2, 7, 2],
    [2, 8, 8, 6, 4, 1, 8, 1],
    [2, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 7, 9],
    [3, 9, 8, 8, 9, 4, 1, 1],
    [8, 9, 2, 4, 2, 8, 4, 3],
    [4, 4, 7, 8, 7, 5, 3, 6],
]
print(list(diagonal(m, 4, 3)))
```

outputs:

```
[5, 2, 6, 4, 4, 1, 3]
```

Comment: I sure misinterpreted the question - probably why my solution didn't match the expected output.

Comment: Thanks @blhsing, this was what I was looking for! I also have a follow up question, how would I change that to get the other diagonal, as in the diagonal in the other direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. It's not beautiful but it gets the job done.

```
def get_diagonal(full_grid, y, x):
    if x > y:
        while y >= 1:
            x -= 1
            y -= 1
    else:
        while x >= 1:
            x -= 1
            y -= 1
    diagonal = []
    while x < len(grid) and y < len(grid[0]):
        diagonal.append(grid[x][y])
        x += 1
        y += 1
    return diagonal

grid = [
    [1, 5, 2, 8, 6, 9, 6, 8],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2, 2, 1],
    [9, 5, 9, 6, 8, 2, 7, 2],
    [2, 8, 8, 6, 4, 1, 8, 1],
    [2, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 7, 9],
    [3, 9, 8, 8, 9, 4, 1, 1],
    [8, 9, 2, 4, 2, 8, 4, 3],
    [4, 4, 7, 8, 7, 5, 3, 6]]

get_diagonal(grid, 5, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems counter-intuitive to me to use "y" along the row and "x" along the vertical, so I've swapped them. If you're OK with starting the indexing at zero, then this worked for me:

```
from random import randint

l = [[str(randint(1,9)) for i in range(8)] for n in range(8)]

# Show the grid
for row in l:
    print(' '.join([str(n) for n in row]))

# Give the initial position, then follow the diagonal down and
# to the right until you run out of rows or columns.
x_pos = 1 
y_pos = 3
diag = []
while x_pos < len(l[0]) and y_pos < len(l):
    diag.append(l[y_pos][x_pos])
    x_pos += 1
    y_pos += 1

print(diag)
```

Sample output:

```
1 3 8 7 3 1 5 2
4 5 8 6 9 4 3 2
2 6 1 3 8 6 8 1
7 1 8 2 7 4 7 4
9 5 5 5 5 2 3 1
8 5 9 7 2 7 1 8
3 3 3 4 2 9 8 3
3 2 8 6 2 4 4 8
['1', '5', '7', '2', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

From @blhsing answer, I think the number iterations should be `min(len(m) - 1 - row, len(m[0]) - 1 - col)` instead.

Let's see an example:
Imagine a matrix with 2 rows:

```
[
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
]
```

Let's say the starting point is the first row, element number four, if we use the original calculation (which is `min((len(m), len(m[0]))) - max((row, col))`) we'll end-up with (min(2,5) - max(0, 3)) = 2 - 3 = -1.

If we use the proposed one (which is `min(len(m) - 1 - row, len(m[0]) - 1 - col)`), we'll have min(2 - 1 - 0, 5 - 1 - 3) = min(1, 1) = 1.